# Error: write EPROTO 34557064:error:100000f7:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
Error: write EPROTO 34557064:error:100000f7:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER:../../third_party/boringssl/src/ssl/tls_record.cc:242:
```

The issue was that I was trying to POST to https when that API actually only supports HTTP.
Just leave this as a note for other folks who might run into the same issue.

Any Help can be appreciated

Comment: Add your code snippet and error screenshot for better clarifications.

Comment: It actually helped me.

Comment: The solution is more like a workaround. A proper API redirects HTTP traffic with a 301 to HTTPS. So, HTTP traffic is not possible on API's with redirect on. 
If you switch on HTTP, then this indeed is a solution because HTTP does not do anything with SSL.

Answer (score 389):

This type of issue comes when you use **https** instead of **http**. Change the URL to use **http**.

Example: `https://localhost:3000/posts`

Change it to: `http://localhost:3000/posts`

Comment: How come does that work? For other methods it works with HTTPS only one bumped me in to this error that is stated in the title of the question.

Comment: Well of course but the point is one should be able to make an HTTPS request also and to test that.

Comment: Very helpful. It works with OAuth2.

Comment: ..and what if we **need** to use HTTPS? not a very helpful answer, on that side.

Answer (score 19):

This error comes when the API that we are hitting is running on http and we are trying using https. Information was really useful.

Example:
Using this https://localhost:8092/customers, when this http://localhost:8092/customers, must be used as API is running on http.

Answer (score 12):

```
error-write-eproto-34557064error100000f7ssl-routinesopenssl-internalwrong

https://localhost:5000/users
```

replace HTTPS to HTTP

Answer (score 4):

I had this issue in Postman when I tried to hit a before working API endpoint.

In my case, it was a Header that I had set manually before and **forgotten** to delete.

**Header: Host**

It has normally the value `<calculated when request is sent>` but I had it given a custom value.

Answer (score 2):

I got this exact error message because I had configured certificates for SSL incompletely in Postman. When specifying URL and port for my certificates, the port input field had a placeholder value of 443, which was the correct one. So I skipped actually typing it.

Turns out I actually had to type it, for it to work.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who is still struggling I had another solution to remove the trailing "/" from my route for example:

```
@app.get("/api/book/{id}/info/")
```

Changed to:

```
@app.get("/api/book/{id}/info")
```

Comment: I think that this is really not the cause of this error.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this error while trying to test the api request on postman. Ensure the the url link specified during the development process is the same url link been used during testing of postman.

example: during development, the url link specified is http://_*****. Then, during testing on postman make sure that the link is the same http://*****.

API requests from Http:// and Https:// are treated and handled differently.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the request was a redirection `302`, in that case, I disable `Automatically follow redirects` on Postman settings
[Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s7fY3.png)

Answer (score 0):

Turn off the "SSL certificate verification" in the settings and check the "Proxy" is correct also. This is aside from validating that the API accepts an HTTPS.

[image]

Usually when you turn off the SSL settings, it should work with both HTTPS/HTTP protocols, as it does not verify the "S" (SSL) part.

Answer (score -3):

I also get the same error while I was accessing the rest API through postman.

```
Https//:localhost:8662/hello
```

Instead of using HTTPS, We can use `HTTP//:localhost:8662/hello`

Now it'll work.

HTTPS-It is an advanced version of HTTP. This comes under SSL protocol which means Security .https encrypt the data so we can use HTTPS when we pass sensitive information like credit card transaction because it encrypts the data.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Your URL format is wrong. It should be `https://localhost:8662/hello`, not `Https//:localhost:8662/hello` or `HTTP//:localhost:8662/hello`.

Comment: @MichaelM. The URL scheme is case in-sensitive, so it really doesn't matter.

Comment: @Tigerrrrr Yes, it isn't case sensitive, but you certainly can't have a preceding colon. The host name `:localhost` is complete nonsense. Take a closer look.