# Parse Error: The server returned a malformed response - Error: Parse Error: Expected HTTP/ - when trying to access one of my app URLs with postman

Tags: python, url, request, postman, tornado

I am managing an app built by third parts in python.

I have this url dispatcher

```
urls += [(r'/path/objectAlpha/(.*)', objectAlphaHandler)]  # this was made by third parts, it is expected to work
```

and this class

```
class objectAlphaHandler(BaseHandler):

    def __init__(self, application, request, **kwargs):
        super(objectAlphaHandler, self).__init__(application, request, **kwargs)  # do the init of the basehandler

    @gen.coroutine
    def post(self, action=''):
        response = {}
        
            ...     
            
            response = yield self.my_method(json_data)
        
            ... 

        self.write(json.dumps(response))

    def my_method(self, json_data)
        ...
```

I want to check that the app correctly receives the request and returns some response.

So I try to access that url with Postman

request type:

```
POST
```

URL:

```
http://<target_machine_ip>:<target_machine_port>/path/objectAlpha/
```

where `<target_machine_port>` is 22.

I get this error from Postman response box

> Parse Error: The server returned a malformed response

and when I click on "view in console" I see

> ```
> POST http://<target_machine_ip>:22/path/objectAlpha/
> Error: Parse Error: Expected HTTP/
> Request Headers
> Content-Type: application/json
> User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.28.4
> Accept: */*
> Postman-Token: d644d7dd-699b-4d77-b32f-46a575ae31fc
> Host: xx.xxx.x.xx:22
> Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
> Connection: keep-alive
> Request Body
> ```

What does `Error: Parse Error: Expected HTTP/` mean?

I checked my app logs but it seems it is not handling any request, even if Postman indicates that the server is returning a (malformed) response.

I also tryed to chenge the target url to:

```
https...
```

but it returns

> ```
>  Error: write EPROTO 28427890592840:error:100000f7:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER:../../third_party/boringssl/src/ssl/tls_record.cc:242:
> ```

which I found out [it indicates I should stick with HTTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62658941/error-write-eproto-34557064error100000f7ssl-routinesopenssl-internalwrong)

Then I tried also:

```
http://<target_machine_ip>/path/objectAlpha/
```

and

```
<target_machine_ip>/path/objectAlpha/
```

which generically return:

> ```
> Error: connect ECONNREFUSED <target_machine_ip>:80
> ```

I also tryed to substitute line

```
urls += [(r'/path/objectAlpha/(.*)', objectAlphaHandler)]
```

with

```
urls += [(r'/path/objectAlpha/', objectAlphaHandler)]
```

and

```
urls += [(r'/path/objectAlpha', objectAlphaHandler)]
```

but none of these worked.

What is wrong? How can I fix it?

### UPDATE

Apparently, according to [this thread](https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/9176#issue-724568528) on Postman Github, the problem happens only on Postman Desktop and not on Postman on browser.

So I tryed to send the request form Postman on my browser but I get

> ```
>  Cloud Agent Error: Can not send requests to reserved address. Make sure address is publicly accessible or select a different agent.
> ```

because, according to [this other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67156814/7658051),

> Postman Website cannot send a request to your computer's localhost. It first needs to connect to your PC with the Postman desktop client

and even if I follow the indications in that answer

> Run it [ndr. Postman desktop], then go to the Postman workspace in your browser -> send the request and it will work.

I still get the same

> ```
> Error: Parse Error: Expected HTTP/
> ```

on both Postman Desktop and Postman on browser.

### UPDATE

Going on debugging, I tryed to cast a curl on that URL from my terminal:

```
myuser@mymachine-VirtualBox:~$ curl --verbose "http://<target_machine_ip>:<target_machine_port>/path/objectAlpha"
```

and I got:

> ```
> *   Trying <target_machine_ip>:<target_machine_port>...
> * Connected to <target_machine_ip> (<target_machine_ip>) port <target_machine_port> (#0)
> > GET /orkpos5/receipt HTTP/1.1
> > Host: <target_machine_ip>:<target_machine_port>    
> > User-Agent: curl/7.74.0    
> > Accept: */*    
> >     
> * Received HTTP/0.9 when not allowed  
>     
> * Closing connection 0    
> curl: (1) Received HTTP/0.9 when not allowed
> ```

Comment: Seems to be a Postman issue in combination with bad headers: https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/9176

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SOLVED

Since the exposed API has been built by third parts for internal use, it is not exposed to the public.

I did not know that, so in the request URL I had put the well-known port number for HTTP requests, the number 22 (see the [list of well-known port numbers.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers)).

To solve the problem, in the request URL, I changed the `<target_machine_port>` to the port on which the API is actually exposed.

request type:

```
POST
```

URL:

```
http://<machine_ip>:<target_machine_port>/path/objectAlpha/
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and the solution was removing `Content-Length` header from the original response.